# Parse strange XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I have a get request returning the following (strange) XML response;

How can i get each val of `<FL val=..>` , as key and the value inside `<FL></FL>` as value?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response uri=" xml/JobOpenings/getRecords">
<result>
    <JobOpenings>
        <row no="1">
            <FL val="JOBOPENINGID">1001</FL>
            <FL val="Posting Title">
                <![CDATA[Controller]]>
            </FL>
            <FL val="Work Experience">
                <![CDATA[Medior]]>
            </FL>
            <FL val="Vacancy type">
                <![CDATA[Not Fixed]]>
            </FL>
            <FL val="Organisation">
                <![CDATA[Organisation B]]>
            </FL>
        </row>
        <row no="2">
            <FL val="JOBOPENINGID">1002</FL>
            <FL val="Posting Title">
                <![CDATA[Accounting & Reporting manager]]>
            </FL>
            <FL val="Job Opening Status">
                <![CDATA[In-progress]]>
            </FL>
            <FL val="Client Name">
                <![CDATA[MVRDO]]>
            </FL>
            <FL val="Work Experience">
                <![CDATA[Medior]]>
            </FL>
            <FL val="Rate">
                <![CDATA[0]]>
            </FL>
            <FL val="Vacancy type">
                <![CDATA[Fixed]]>
            </FL>
            <FL val="Specialisme">
                <![CDATA[Finance]]>
            </FL>
             <FL val="Organisation">
                <![CDATA[Organisation A]]>
            </FL>
        </row>
    </JobOpenings>
</result>
</response>
```

Example output that i want is a array with

key=Vacancy Type, value=Not Fixed

key = Organization, value = Organization B

etc..

I know that i need a double foreach like:

```
    $array=simplexml_load_string($xml);    
    foreach ($array->result->JobOpenings->row as $item){
         foreach($item->children() as $key => $value){

            echo '{$key} : {$value} </br>'; //But what to do here??
         }
    }
```

The above code gives the output:

FL : Not Fixed

FL : Organisation B

but i need FL to be the value of val= inside of `<FL val="This">`

Comment: after json tranccformation i lost comments (<![CDATA). I need use xmal parser to get that walue

Comment: the json transform is not necessary, i just tried it in my own example. Feel free to lose the transformation

Answer (score 0):

This code descends to value you ask. Probably, you want more sophisticated lookup, but I can't understand that from your question

```
$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($doc->result->{0}->JobOpenings->{0}->row as $row)
    foreach($row as $item) {
        if(isset($item['val'])) echo $item['val'] .' ';
        echo $item . "\n"; 
    }
```

[demo](https://eval.in/579500)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, except this is not the response that i expect.
What i need is to iterate through every row and every FL, i need to get all FL key and values and safe these in a array

Comment: have a look at this [demo](https://eval.in/579533) this is more likely that i want except that FL needs to be the '$item['val'] value in your example